# How to initiate Closing handshaking between java serversocket and websocket

Tags: java, javascript, websocket

I have a java ServeSocket that is connected to a websocket(client) , the starting handshaking is going well and the connection is established and data is recieved (sent from client to server) but I need to implement the Closing handshake protocol now , from what I have found is that , I need to send a closing Frame from the Server to the client but I can't figure out how to Implement this correctly this what I did till now

```
 private static final byte[] closeFrame = new byte[] { (byte) 0xde,
                 (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x0 };

out.println(closeFrame); // out is a PrintWriter to socket
```

Takes too long time for the client to respond also

Comment: dont mix up network-packages and java sockets; be granted that the java socket is ABOVE the TCP/IP-Layer, so you can simply send data (which is mostly byte[]) as you wish; if you wan to close the connection, tell your server to close the connected client (client.close() ).

Comment: I would do that , but it seems that browsers without proper handshake closing , they keep trying to reconnect to the server socket

Comment: now i',m curious; how does the browser connect to your server? is it a mere web browser?